# Output Channel Entry {status} to Lowercase Slug

Tags: status

Is there a **documented** (core) way to output the status as lowercase?  What if the status is two words - is there a way to output the status with a hyphen?

i.e.:

Status name in Control Panel: **In Progress**

```
{status}
```

Would output:

```
in-progress
```

If there isn't a documented way, could you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unable to write your own PHP for it, you can use the add-on [Streeng](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng) to wrap around `{status}` in your template with the slug parameter.

```
{exp:streeng slug="yes"}{status}{/exp:streeng}
```